# Bootstrap datepicker + momentJS - Firefox "Invalid date"

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, momentjs, bootstrap-datepicker

I used bootstrap datepicker with moment.js.

Same method works fine on Chrome browser. On Firefox, it shows `Invalid date`.

If I change `format` to `dateFormat`, it works in Firefox. It changes date value to `MM/DD/YYYY` format.
But, I need to display `dd-MM-YYYY` format in input field.

Please let me know what I missed out in the code that is causing Firefox not to work

Here my javascript code:

**JS:**

```
$('.pickerdate').datepicker({
   startDate: today,
   format: 'dd-mmm-yyyy',
   orientation: 'bottom',
   autoclose: true,
   endDate: "+1y"
});

var $returnDate = moment($('.pickerdate').val()).format('YYYYMMDDhhmm');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `Invalid date` on firefox because you are trying to parse a string that it's not in ISO 8601 format. As momentjs [parsing docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) says:

> **Warning:** Browser support for parsing strings [is inconsistent](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html). Because there is no specification on which formats should be supported, what works in some browsers will not work in other browsers.
>
> For consistent results parsing anything other than ISO 8601 strings, you should use [String + Format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

So you have to use [`moment(String, String);`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/). In your case:

```
moment($('.pickerdate').val(), 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

Anyway note that you can use the [`getDate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#getdate) method to get datepicker's value. As the docs states, it

> Returns a localized date object representing the internal date object of the first datepicker in the selection

---

Here a working example that shows how to get the date from the picker (and print it to console in your custom format with moment) using both datepicker's `getDate` and moment parsing with format. I suggest to use the `getDate` version.

```js
var today = moment().toDate();
$('.pickerdate').datepicker({
   startDate: today,
   format: 'dd-M-yyyy',
   orientation: 'bottom',
   autoclose: true,
   endDate: "+1y"
});

$('#btn1').click(function(){
  var date = $('.pickerdate').datepicker('getDate');
  if( !date ) return;
  var $returnDate = moment(date).format('YYYYMMDDhhmm');
  console.log($returnDate);
});
$('#btn2').click(function(){
  var val = $('.pickerdate').val();
  if( !val ) return;
  var $returnDate = moment(val, 'DD-MMM-YYYY').format('YYYYMMDDhhmm');
  console.log($returnDate);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control pickerdate">
<button id="btn1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Get date picker</button>
<button id="btn2" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Get date moment</button>
```

---

Please note that bootstrap datepicker and momentjs use different format tokens. <s>My example uses 2-digit month number,</s> if you need to use abbreviated and full month names use:

- `M`, `MM` for [bootstrap datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#format)
- `MMM`, `MMMM` for [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

Comment: Hi Vince, Sorry for late comeback.. In Input box, it have to show like "07-Dec-2016". then i need to use momentJS to convert as '201612071000' on submit form.

Comment: Please let me know how can i get this output.. if its possible to do so or any alternative solution to solve this issue. Our client dont want 12/07/2016 format on input field.

Comment: @TDG I've updated my answer's snippet in order to show dates like `07-Dec-2016`. I've just changed format according docs, as I already described in the last part of my answer, hope that now it's clearer. As a general advice, do not add details to your question in the comments, edit the question instead; moreover upvote & accept if you think an answer solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments and instruction!!